# Applying raster symbology to raster layer with different values using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, symbology, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and starting with an 8 bit raster layer that has specific symbology and labeling - a value of 0 is labeled as a certain species, and so on.
[image: symbology layer]

I want to apply this symbology/labeling to another raster that has the same data, but has been masked against another layer. Thus, some values (such as 1 and 2) are no longer included in the layer.

[image: input layer]

How can I apply the symbology from my first layer to my second layer?

I tried using the Apply Symbology from Layer tool, but I got an error that the symbol layer does not match the input layer.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing just a little bit of detail in your screenshots that makes me think you're going to have some other issues crop up.

Can you please let us know how the symbology is being assigned in the first (working) example you gave. Is the field being symbolised the "Label" field, or something else?

For example, here I am symbolising DonutType
[image]

In your second example does that same field exist?

If the answer is that the same field exists in both datasets, then the below might help.

Right click the layer you have successfully symbolised in the Content Pane, Select Sharing, then Save as Layer file. 
[image: How to save a layer file in ArcGIS Pro]

Then, left click your 2nd layer to which you would like to apply the symbols. On the top menu select appearance, then import symbology. In the import pane select the layer file. 
[image]

Hope that helps.

Alternatively, when you do Symbology - Import, you can select to import it directly from another layer that you already have loaded. This is faster, but the lyr method is safer in terms of repeatability between projects and map documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first raster layer does not have an attribute table, so I'm not sure what field is being symbolized. I also am not seeing an Import button under the Appearance tab.

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot by editing your initial question in which we can see the whole application - including the contents pane, the symbology pane, and the top menu set to the appearance tab. 

The manus in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 are contextual, so it's probably easier for us to point and show if we've got more context ourselves